# How to find a specific digit from large number and count that?

Tags: php, substr, execution-time, strlen, largenumber

Here i try to find out all 2's and count them from a given number .
i already did it.
But my code worked for small number like 
$number=25, but if $number=10000000000;then unable to echo $n ,i think because of execution time . Any better ways for large number??

```
<?php
$n =0 ;
$number =25;
for($j = 1; $j<=$number ; $j++)
{
$l = strlen($j);
for($i =0;$i<$l;$i++)
{
$d = substr($j,$i,1);

    if($d ==2)
    {
        $n++;
    }

  }
 }
 echo $n;
 // answer is 9

?>
```

Comment: Wait, why is the answer 9? What is it this is supposed to do?

Comment: For $n =25 , answer is 9 , answer will change based on $n.
Such as $n =100, answer is 20 ..... is it clear ? @Don'tPanic

Comment: Can you explain how there are 9 2s in 25?

Comment: yes 
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25....
here is 9 2s .... from 1 to 25 u will get 9 2s :)... sum of all 2 .

Comment: Ahh, I get it. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: yes!! welcome . But unfortunately my code is not working for large number .... looking for better solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can avoid the string conversion just using modulo.

**PHP**

```
<?php

$count = 0;
$n = (int) $argv[1];

for ($i = 0; $i <= $n; $i++) {
    $ii = $i;
    while ($ii > 1) {
        if ($ii % 10 == 2) {
            $count++;
        }
        $ii /= 10;
    }
}

echo $count;
```

If I run `php run.php 1e8` I'll get:

```
User time (seconds): 117.98
System time (seconds): 1.17
Percent of CPU this job got: 95%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 2:05.00
```

---

**C**

Just to compare, I wrote the same script using C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double n;
    sscanf(argv[1], "%lf", &n);
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        int ii = i;
        while (ii > 1) {
            if (ii % 10 == 2) {
                count++;
            }
            ii /= 10;
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Using the same number `./count 1e8` I get this:

```
User time (seconds): 1.21
System time (seconds): 0.00
Percent of CPU this job got: 98%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:01.24
```

Comment: ohh! yes ... avoid string conversion and using mod just decrease execution time ... thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

> Here i try to find out all 2's and count them from a given number . i already did it. But my code worked for small number like $number=25, but if $number=10000000000;then unable to echo $n ,i think because of execution time . Any better ways for large number??

what you describe should be rather like

```
<?php

// clunky version with a loop
function countInStr($str, $chr) {
    $n = 0;
    $l = strlen( $str );
    for( $i =0; $i < $l; $i++ ) { 

        if( $chr == substr($str, $i, 1) ) {
            $n++;
        }

    }
    return $n;
}

$number = 25;
$sum=0;
for ( $i=0; $i <= $number ; $i++ ) {
    //echo $i." ";
    $sum += countInStr( $i, '2' );
}
echo $sum." ?= 9";

// x        counted in 1*10^x
/*
$known[6] = 600000; //1000000
$known[5] = 50000;  //100000
$known[4] = 4000;   //10000
$known[3] = 300;    //1000
$known[2] = 20;     //100
$known[1] = 1;      //10
*/

?>
```

- numeric types are defined only for certain ranges, so that would limit the length
- instead use array (lists) or strings, then you are much less limited
- no idea what the two loops have been for, but following your description you wanted to do just one counting loop; the array answer also fits the question, no idea why people vote others trying to help down
- sum of counted digits within the range (0,max) added for the example
- as you can see in the list `$known` (that is true for counting all digits, not only 2) you can do it more intelligent with an algorithm that tells the huger numbers apart and replaces the "stupid" counting. have a look on functions like `log()`, `pow()` for that arithmetic; hint: it's a bit like transforming numbers from one number system into another

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not i am looking for. For $n =25 , answer is 9 , answer will change based on $n. Such as $n =100, answer is 20 
Here i am looking for count all 2 's From 1 to given number ..... is it clear ?

Comment: actually not clear, in number 25 there is only two digits: 2 and 5. so counting 2 it makes one single appearance. please edit the question for what exactly you want to count.

Comment: yes 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,‌​24,25.... here is 9 2s .... from 1 to 25 u will get 9 2s :)... sum of all 2 ... now ??

Comment: ok, as you see no problem to add. just the issue with long runtime remains. you could circumvent this with precalculated arrays for larger portions.

Comment: hinted you on doin it a more intelligent – and thus less time consuming – way; your decision if you implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for

```
function count_char_in_string($str,$char){  // This one counts the $char in a single string
    $str="".$str;   // Convert to a string actually
    $total=0;
    for ($ix=0;$ix<strlen($str);$ix++){
        if (substr($str,$ix,1)==$char) {
            $total++;
        }
    }
    return $total;
}

$n=25000;
$total=0;
for ($ix=0;$ix<=$n;$ix++){
     $total+=count_char_in_string($ix,"2");
}
echo $total;
```